# Codeigniter URL - Characters being removed when using url_title()

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am using `url_title($location['name'])` to append the names of locations onto the end of their respective URLs rather than the IDs.

Some of the locations I have in my DB include characters such as 'Ø,Ã and Ä. `url_title()` is simply removing these from the URL and thus making the links inoperable.

I have tried adding these characters to `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`, but no luck.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to put the ids in the url with your title 
like mysite.com/view/id/22/mytitle

but you can 
try `convert_accented_characters()`

in Codeigniter helper http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html

```
url_title(convert_accented_characters($location['name']));
```